# Figure up how to implement dynamic JSON manipulation

Tags: c#, json, xml

My issue is this:

I am trying to send a JSON that represent an Order to a API.

This is the [structure](http://v44i.imgup.net/orderc9c3.png) of the problem that i am facing

and those are some examples of the orders:

1. multiply shipment and items, [orders](http://pastebin.com/EiAr6pKK)
2. one shipment and multiply items, [orders](http://pastebin.com/UhKC9qas)
3. one shipment and one item, [order](http://pastebin.com/tqMuC3Eh)

-> i am hoping that i covered all the cases

This JSON is built from an XML, that is built dynamically each time the customer wants to order something.

- he can order, multiply shipment, and multiply items - the function needs to take care of it.

I am having trouble to struct a function that will handle all the case
and write the correct ID's.

For now this is what i wrote(i am writing the values to the XML and then i am 
serialize it to JSON with the help of `newtonsoft` - this is working fine)

```
public void SendOrder(string renderedOutput, string orderID)
{
    var xml = XElement.Parse(renderedOutput);
    var elmOrderData = xml.Element("orderData").Descendants();  
    var shipmentsIds = GetShipmentsIds(orderID);

    int shipmentId = 0; 
    int shipmentId_index = 0;

    foreach (var el in elmOrderData)
    {// the correct order according to the xml template
        if (el.Name == "shipmentIndex" && el.Attribute("Name").Value == "items")
        {// items -> shipmentIndex
            el.SetValue(shipmentId);
        }

        if (el.Name == "shipmentIndex" && el.Attribute("Name").Value == "shipments")
        {// shipments -> shipmentIndex
            el.SetValue(shipmentId);
        }

        if (el.Name == "sourceShipmentId")
        {
            var sourceShipmentIndex = shipmentsIds[shipmentId_index];
            el.SetValue(sourceShipmentIndex);

            shipmentId++;
            shipmentId_index++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You know, if it were me, I'd make a little object that knew how to serialize/deserialize to and from xml and json. Then I'd just use that to read in the xml and spit out the json. Cuz i'm lazy like that.  =)

Comment: @Nikki9696 - i did that(i think) , this is just piece of code taken from a much bigger code..  Can you give an example?